# Python - Why SIGTERM terminate parent process even if it was only sent to child process?

Tags: python, signals, fastapi

I'm new to handling signals in python. I want to run a server using fastapi. In the server, there is a time-consuming service (with url: "/run" in the code) that might be killed from outside (with url: "/stop").

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool
import os
import uvicorn
import signal
from sub import run_loop

app = FastAPI()

def run_py(**kwargs):
    i = kwargs['i']
    try:
        out = ProcessingPool().map(run, [[i]])[0]
    except SystemError as err:
        out = 114514

    return out

def run(args):
    re_fig = run_loop(args[0])
    return re_fig

@app.post("/run")
def run_main():
    i = 1
    out = run_py(i=i)
    return JSONResponse({"code": 200, "message": out})

@app.post("/stop")
def stop():
    with open("./pid.txt", "r") as f:
        pid = int(f.readline())
    os.kill(pid, signal.SIGTERM)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app='test:app', host="0.0.0.0", port=1145, reload=False)
```

And I set a SIGTERM handler in the subprocess:

```py
import signal
import os
import time

def loop(i):
    pid = os.getpid()
    with open("./pid.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(str(pid))

    while i < 30:
        i += 1
        print(f"sleep {i}")
    return i

def run_loop(i):
    def sigterm_handler(_signo, _stack_frame):
        print("stop!!!!!!!!!!!!")
        raise SystemError

    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, sigterm_handler)

    i = loop(i)
    return i
```

When I trigger the `sigterm_handler` by sending request to "/stop", I was expecting only the subprocess loop is stopped and raise a `SystemError` so that `out` can be set to 114514 in the main process. Well this is achieved but the entire server is also stopped:

```bash
INFO:     Started server process [108395]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:1145 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
sleep 2
sleep 3
sleep 4
sleep 5
sleep 6
stop!!!!!!!!!!!!
INFO:     127.0.0.1:57480 - "POST /stop HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
INFO:     127.0.0.1:57476 - "POST /run HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
INFO:     Shutting down
INFO:     Waiting for application shutdown.
INFO:     Application shutdown complete.
INFO:     Finished server process [108395]
```

How can I only kill the subprocess instead of terminating the entire server?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the start_method for multiprocessing to spawn method and your child process will be clear (without inherited signal handlers, thread pools and other stuff).

```py
@app.on_event("startup")
async def on_startup():
    multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')
```